# Проектирование БД с использованием отношения многие ко многим

Tags: sql, база-данных, проектирование

Здравствуйте!

Нужно спроектировать БД для компании, которая осуществляет обработку запросов. В компании работают несколько специалистов, которые могут выполнять над запросами действия различных типов. Каждый специалист может выполнить действие каждого типа над одним и тем же запросом. Нужно разработать схему БД для данной компании.

На основе полученной БД нужно составить sql-запрос, который будет выводить две колонки: сотрудник и премия. Где премия - ежемесячная выплата специалисту за выполнение над запросом действия определенного типа, таким образом, что за один запрос премия выдается только один раз в истории и только одному специалисту — тот кто самым первым выполнил это действие над запросом. Размер премии на один запрос составляет 5$.

Я так понимаю нужны 3 таблицы: специалисты (employees), действия (actions) и запросы (requests).
Изначально у меня идея такая: промежуточная таблица действий различных типов (actions) связывает между собой работников (employees) и запросы над которыми они работают (requests). В таблице (requests) каждый запрос имеет столбец id действия определенного типа, за которое начисляется премия (action_id_for_reward) и id специалиста, который первым выполнил это действие (employee_id_for_reward), данный столбец по дефолту null.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правильна ли логика моих рассуждений?

SQL-запрос который я пока имею, следующий:

```
SELECT u.full_name, 5 * COUNT(*) as reward 
FROM users as u
LEFT OUTER JOIN actions as a
  ON u.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN requests as o
  ON a.request_id = o.request_id 
    AND a.action_id = o.action_id_reward
      AND u.user_id = o.user_id_reward
```

Updated: изменил схему БД на основе комментариев:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На схеме выше предполагается, что столбец is_done по умолчанию false, если конкретное действие выполнено, то is_done true и устанавливается текущая дата в date.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70155/discussion-on-question-by-ary211------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем трюк с получением значения поля для

```
SELECT E.full_name, 5 * count(1) as reward
  FROM employees E
  JOIN (
    SELECT substr(min(concat(`date`,employee_id)),20) as employee_id
      FROM actions A
     WHERE A.action_name='NAME'
           -- and date between X and Y  (если надо за конкретный месяц)
     GROUP BY A.order_id
  ) X
    ON E.employee_id=X.employee_id
 GROUP BY E.employee_id, E.full_name
```

Comment: извините, что так назойливо интересуюсь!
Пытаюсь разобраться в запросе:

1. Как это работает: min(concat(`date`,employee_id)), мы ведь тут просто делаем конкатенацию строки 'date' и столбца employee_id, а потом используем min для несуществующего столбца 'date employee_id', разве нет?

2. Зачем после ON нужно ещё группировать строки аж по двум столбцам: GROUP BY E.employee_id, E.full_name?

P.S. Огромное вам спасибо за ваш суппорт!

Comment: @Ary211 Там date в обратных апострофах, а в не обычных. В MySQL в обратных апострофах пишутся имена колонок, а не текст. так что мы склеиваем содержимое колонки date и содержимое employee_id, в итоге выходит что то вроде `2017113099` (для employee_id=99). далее получаем минимальную строку (в которой как раз минимальная дата) и из этой минимальной substr() достаем обратно 99. group by по id нужен потому что могут быть 2 человека с одинаковыми именами, а по имени, потому что имя есть в select, а последние версии MySQL и другие СУБД требуют, что бы все колонки, присутствующие в select были в grou